# Why the geodesic active contour split into a lot of tiny contours in image processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

When I apply matlab coding of geodesic active contour with additive operator splitting scheme, the output is not as my expectation? Can someone help me to improve this?

First picture is the result that I obtained, and the second picture is the result that I expected (blue line).

[image: my result]

[image: expected result]

Here is my complete gac matlab code:

```
clc;
tic
A='D:\data\desktop\GAC-CNN\';
B=dir(fullfile(A,'*.png'));
f=fullfile(A,B.name);
I=imread(f);
I=double(I(:,:,1));

imshow(I/255);


%%%  Stopping Function for edge detection    

t = cputime;
% % function g = Stopfunction( u, k , sigma)
sigma= 0.5;
mask = fspecial( 'gaussian', 1,sigma); %try and error
u2 = conv2( I, mask , 'same');

k=1;
[ ux,uy ] = gradient(I);
g = 1 ./ (1 + k * (ux .^ 2 +  uy .^ 2));
Balloon = -10; % default = 0.3
tau = 10;


%%%%  Initial Condition


% % a = Ini_square(u, d)
[m, n] = size (u2);

d=10; % change according to image size

for i =1:min(floor ((m+1)/2),floor((n+1)/2))
    
    u2 (i, i:n-i+1 ) = (i-d);
    u2 (i:m-i+1,i) =(i-d);
    u2 (m-i+1, i:n-i+1) = (i-d);
    u2 (i:m-i+1,n-i+1) =(i-d);
end


%%%% AOS

iter=300; 
for j=1:iter
    % % u = AOS_Active_Contour2( u, Balloon, tau , g);
    %% an automatic convergence condition
    if (j > 1 && isequal(u1,u2))
        break;
    end
    u1 = u2;
    
    [ux,uy]=gradient(I);
    
    Dphi = sqrt(ux.^2 + uy.^2 + 1e-10);
    %     Dphi = sqrt(ux.^2 + uy.^2);
    % %  absDphi = upwind2 (Phi);
    % Initialization
    Dxf = zeros(size(u2));
    Dxb = zeros(size(u2));
    Dyf = zeros(size(u2));
    Dyb = zeros(size(u2));
    
    % Backward and forward derivatives
    Dxf(1:end-1,:) = u2(2:end,:) - u2(1:end-1,:);
    Dxb(2:end,:) = u2(2:end,:) - u2(1:end-1,:);
    Dyf(:,1:end-1) = u2(:,2:end) - u2(:,1:end-1);
    Dyb(:,2:end) = u2(:,2:end) - u2(:,1:end-1);
    
    % Gradients in x and y direction
    gradVecX = zeros(size(u2));
    gradVecY = gradVecX;
    gradVecX = max(Dxb,0) + min(Dxf,0);
    gradVecY = max(Dyb,0) + min(Dyf,0);
    
    % Gradient magnitude
    gradMag = sqrt((max(Dxb,0)).^2 + (min(Dxf,0)).^2 ...
        + (max(Dyb,0)).^2 + (min(Dyf,0)).^2);
    
    absDphi = gradMag;
     
    
    Balloon_force=  Balloon .* g .*absDphi;
    u2 = u2 + tau .* Balloon_force;
    
    if mod(j,10)==0
        imagesc(I,[0 255]); colormap(gray);hold on;
        [c, h] = contour(u2, [0 0], 'r');
        iterNum = [num2str(j), 'iterations'];
        title(iterNum);
        pause(0.02);
    end
    u2 = (u2 >= 0) - ( u2< 0);% the selective step.
    u2 = conv2(u2, mask, 'same');
    
end

time = cputime-t;
figure(1);
imagesc(I);colormap(gray);

hold on;
contour(u2, [0 0], 'r','LineWidth',1);
toc
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To adequately answer your question, it'd be good to supply the exact steps you're taking to produce the first image as well as how the second "correct" image was derived.

Comment: The code is attached as above for the first picture, but I don't have the code for the second picture, that one I extracted from another article about gac, and in my mind, it would be the correct image that I should get.  I tried to change the parameters k, balloon, tau and d, but the outputs are almost the same with the first picture.